# iOS Safari: Hide AdressBar / NavigationBar without Scrolling

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile-safari, fullscreen

I am developing a single page web app.
The web app contains of a surrounding framework (mainly header and off-canvas menu) and a scrollable content area, which is a viewport nested inside the html hierarchy deeper down.

Since the scrollable area is a nested oart if the whole page, the main web page itself stays at a fixed position and doesn't scroll.
Apparently this hinders me from using

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

to set Safari into full screen mode.

Is there any other way for me to hide AddressBar (and NavigationBar)?

Thanks in advance,
Sascha.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7.1 there is a new meta viewport option `minimal-ui` that will hide the address bar and navigation bar:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

You can check this link on iOS 7.1 device, it will open without address bar and navigation bar: http://www.initlabs.com/sample/ios7mobileweb.html

Here is more details on iOS and full screen mode: http://blog.initlabs.com/post/81716286465/how-to-display-websites-in-fullscreen-mode-in-ios7